# How to create an alerting alarm on android event in silent mode?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I want to create an anti theft alarm, so when the android device is stolen, it should make a loudly alert. I tried this code, but it does not work.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(300);

    Uri alert = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        //mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this to override the phone volume settings:

```
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: If you mean the code in Michael's original question is not working, that is because the "mMediaPlayer.prepare();" must be uncommented (at least on 4.4.4, it is required -- I tried myself).  Curious that no one else pointed this out.

Comment: This works great - but I don't want to fiddle around with the user's choice to silence his phone... what I need is JUST ONE notification to make noise, because it is an alarm that needs to be delivered. If I use this solution, the mute is off after my alarm... :(

Comment: Just store the existing state before the change and return the phone to that state after your notification